# Unable to Wrap Relative Layout around Image Loaded using Picaso

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview with custom adaptor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_list_item_bg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_thumb"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 

       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_thumb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_thumb"
         android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_dealer_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
         android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

product_list_item_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="5dp">
 <solid android:color="#c6e2b2"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

When i use the dummy placeholder the row correctly wraps around the image but when a custom image is loaded using picaso in the adaptor there is gap left on the top and bottom.

```
   Picasso.with(context)
   .load(img_url)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.dummy_placeholder)
   .error(R.drawable.dummy_placeholder)
   .into(holder.iv_ThumbImage);
```

I tried using wrap_content in relative layout it does not work.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot what you want to achieve and what is happening now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean your `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView` are not resizing while you set a new `Bitmap` to your `ImageView`, I think setting the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds` of `ImageView` to `true` will do your work. Of course the `height` and `width` of your `ImageView` and `RelativeLayout` need to be `wrap_content`